# Replacing specific words in text with words from another list python

Tags: python, reddit

I've written a short script to use Reddit's PRAW API to search a subreddit for articles and if certain word/words are in the article title, replace those words with a random word taken from a list of other words.  I'm putting it in a dictionary because I'm going to write the url & article title to a database before tweeting it out so I don't send out duplicates.  I'm mostly curious if there's a better way to write the `replacer()` function.

For example: "World leaders brace for Trump's speech" --> "World leaders brace for spongebob's speech"

`nicknames` in `matches()` is a list of nicknames from another file.

```
def replacer(title, words, randoms):
    '''title is string you want to split.
       words is a list of words you are looking to match. 
       randoms is a list of random words to replace with words.'''

    new_title = []
    for word in title.split(' '):
        if word in words:
            word = random.choice(randoms)
        new_title.append(word)

    return ' '.join(new_title)


def matches(login, subreddit):

    page = login.subreddit(subreddit)

    # used for the any statement 
    combined_names = ["Name's", "Mister Name's", "Firstname Lastname", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Mister Firstname", "Mister Lastname"]

    # target words to replace 
    names_apost = ["Name's", "Mister Name's"] 
    names_no_apost = ["Firstname Lastname", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Mister Firstname", "Mister Lastname"]

    # for appropriate conjugation 
    nicknames_apostrophe = [i + "'s" for i in nicknames]

    post_dict = {}
    top_posts = page.hot(limit=100)
    for post in top_posts:
        title = post.title
    if any(word in title for word in combined_names):
        first_iter = replacer(post.title, names_apost, nicknames_apostrophe)
        second_iter = replacer(first_iter, names_no_apost, nicknames)
        if post.ups > 1000: 
            value = post.ups, post.url
            post_dict[second_iter] = value
    return post_dict
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that the condition `if word in words` in `replacer` performs a linear search on `words` if it's a list, as in the current code. Since this condition is executed for every word in the input, it would be good to optimize it a bit. You could for example pass a `set` of words instead of a `list`.

The names `first_iter` and `second_iter` are not very meaningful. It would be good to come up with some better names for these.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your question about the `replacer` function, you can shorten it a bit by using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehension):

```
def replacer(title, words, randoms):
    """
    :param title: string you want to split.
    :param words: list of words you are looking to match.
    :param randoms: list of random words to replace with words.
    :return: new title
    """

    return ' '.join([random.choice(randoms) if word in words else word 
                    for word in title.split()])
```

From the docs:

> The method `split()` returns a `list` of all the words in the string,
>   using str as the separator (**splits on all whitespace if left
>   unspecified**), optionally limiting the number of splits to num

More, there's this [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) thing which tells Python programmers how they can style their code according to some simple *rules*:

- for example, when writing docstrings you should use triple doubled-quotes

Comment: you don't even need the `list expression`. A `generator expression` would work just as well and not instantiate the list